# How to create a paragraph header centered and with '(a)' label

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

For my \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis} in subsection 2.3.4 I created code for paragraphs:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}
\subsection{The reasons of wide values}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alph{paragraph}}
\paragraph{State of the vegetation}
\paragraph{Climate} 
\paragraph{Methods}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\arabic{subparagraph}}
\subparagraph{Lysimeters}
\subparagraph{Energy balance}
\subparagraph{Water balance}
```

But I want my paragraphs look like this:

```
2.3.4 The reasons of wide values

Some text

                           (a) State of vegetation
Some text

                           (b) Climate
Some text

                           (c) Methods
1.Lysimeters.-Some text

2.Energy balance.-Some text

3.Water balance.-Some text
```

What do I need to change in the code for the look I want?

Please forgive me if I use wrongly LaTex terminology. I am new to the LaTex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the package `sectsty`, but it doesn't provide centering for `paragraph` and `subparagraph`, but to indent.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\paragraphfont{\hspace*{0.2\linewidth}\centering}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{(\alph{paragraph})}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\arabic{subparagraph}}

\begin{document}
\subsection{The reasons of wide values}
\paragraph{State of the vegetation}
\paragraph{Climate} 
\paragraph{Methods}
\subparagraph{Lysimeters}
\subparagraph{Energy balance}
\subparagraph{Water balance}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted. Only how to make/put points after 1. Lysimeters. and then some text at the same line?

Comment: To get points after the subparagraph numbers just define: `\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\arabic{subparagraph}.}`. For a point after Lysimeters add one.